# Problema com retorno de página de acordo com perfil C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando retornar uma página de acordo com o perfil do usuário cadastrado no banco.
Se o perfil dele for "Admin" retorna uma outra página.
Tento com o perfil de Administrador e funciona, já de um outro usuário, mudei o perfil dele no banco e não retorna o perfil certo.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?
*Meu código é este:*

```
 public ActionResult LogOn(FormCollection f, string returnUrl)
        {
            Conta user = new Conta();
            ContaModels atrrConta = new ContaModels();
            atrrConta = user.RetornaUser(f["login"]);
            if (user.AutenticaUser(atrrConta, f["senha"]))
            {
                //Rotina para autenticar usuario
                if (returnUrl == "" || returnUrl == null)
                {
                    returnUrl = "../CalendarioAlertaSMS";
                }
                System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(f["login"], false);

                Session["PERFIL"] = atrrConta.Ide_Perfil;
                if (Session["PERFIL"].ToString() == "ADMIN")
                {
                    returnUrl = "../PainelAdm";
                }

                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else {
                ViewBag.Message = "Login ou senha inválidos.";
                return View(); 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tenta usar isso no lugar do redirect:

```
return RedirectToAction("NomeDaAction");
```

Comment: Não aparece esse método pra mim aqui não @Rafael Cabral.

Comment: retorna algum erro? se continuar não funcionando voce pode usar o 'return View("nomeAction")'

Comment: É que estou iniciando em MVC agora, só manjo de webforms. rs

Comment: rs, um exemplo pra voce entender melhor:

`return RedirectToAction("Details");`

ai ele vai retornar para a actionresult Details do controle

Comment: Tentei, só que ele não reconhece o RedirectToAction. Precisa importar alguma biblioteca ?