# Controller não passa valor da rota para a View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Com base na minha pergunta anterior: [Problema com retorno de página de acordo com perfil C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70755/problema-com-retorno-de-p%C3%A1gina-de-acordo-com-perfil-c/70759?noredirect=1#comment145041_70759)
Ao acessar o sistema com outro usuário com o Perfil "ADMIN", o retorno do controller não cai na view e não chama a rota da página que deveria retornar.
Já acessando com o "Administrador do Sistema" funciona.
O que pode estar acontecendo ?

```
public ActionResult LogOn(FormCollection f, string returnUrl)
        {
            Conta user = new Conta();
            ContaModels atrrConta = new ContaModels();
            atrrConta = user.RetornaUser(f["login"]);
            if (user.AutenticaUser(atrrConta, f["senha"]))
            {
                //Rotina para autenticar usuario
                if (returnUrl == "" || returnUrl == null)
                {
                    returnUrl = "../CalendarioAlertaSMS";
                }
                System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(f["login"], false);

                Session["PERFIL"] = atrrConta.Ide_Perfil;
                if (Session["PERFIL"].ToString() == "ADMIN")
                {
                    returnUrl = "../PainelAdm";
                }

                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else {
                ViewBag.Message = "Login ou senha inválidos.";
                return View(); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Você tem dois perfis, "Admin" e "Administrador de Sistema", é isso mesmo?

Comment: @Cigano Morrison Mendez Tenho um usuário admin e outro normal, só que com o perfil de administrador.
No caso está igual, só muda o nome de usuário.

Comment: Pode colocar aqui na sua pergunta o código atualizado?

Comment: Eu tinha aberto outro forum onde postei ele. Mas vou colocar novamente, perai .. :)

Comment: Pronto Cigano ..

Comment: `SetAuthCookie` não devia ser a primeira instrução dentro do `if`?

Comment: Ó tipo, quando eu acesso com o usuário administrador que tem o perfil de admin funciona direitinho, ele retorna a página certa que no caso é essa "../PainelAdm". Ai troquei o perfil de um usuário e coloquei ele como admin, com isso era pra retornar essa página também e não retorna. Coloquei um breakpoint na view e quando acesso como administrador ele cai nele, mas ai quando acesso com esse usuário não cai nele ..

Comment: Tentei passando o SetAuthCookie primeiro mas mesmo assim não funcionou ..

Comment: Cara, deste novo usuário que você esta testando a informação que vem de: `atrrConta.Ide_Perfil;` é ADMIN em caixa alta? pois se não for não vai mesmo.

Comment: É caixa alta sim @IvanTeles. Consegui cara. Obrigado.

Comment: O problema era uma Role em um local "escondido" que estava permitindo o acesso para a página somente para usuário Admin, não usuários que continham perfil "Admin".